# How do you install a resource pack in Minecraft 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found the resource pack folder in `Appdata\roaming\.minecraft`, the one that opens up when when I click on "open resource pack folder" in the Minecraft game.

I downloaded a resource pack and want to install it, but it will not let me drag and drop or copy and paste this resource pack zipped folder into the "available resource packs" area in the game.

How do I get the resource pack to open up into the game?

Comment: Are you by any chance unzipping (extracting) the resource folders before placing them in your resource pack folder?

Comment: Hi Ben.  I think I might have unzipped it before placing it in my resource pack folder.  So I deleted the folder and downloaded it again as a zipped file.  Then I tried to copy and paste and drag and drop the unzipped folder into the "available resource packs" area and unfortunately I still can't get access to it.  Great idea you shared.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: You may need to place it directly into the `.minecraft\resource packs` folder manually.

Comment: That's sound like a good idea- but how do I manually place it directly into the .minecraft/resource pack folder? LOL :)  As you can see, I am new at this.  This is my first downloaded resource pack!

Comment: Ben, BTW, the hogcraft folder is already in my appdata-roaming-.minecraft-resourcepacks folder.  Does that mean it is where it should be?  It so, then the problem is accessing the folder.

Comment: Ok, so is that the unzipped version? And have you restarted Minecraft since it was placed in there?

Comment: @Ben These are the exact same questions I would have asked, +1

Comment: Hi guys.  Yes, it is the unzipped version?  And after your comment, I restarted Minecraft after it was placed there. Same problem :)

Comment: Ok, try copy/pasting the zipped version (the one you re-downloaded) and placing it in the `Appdata\Roaming\.minecraft\resource packs` folder, run Minecraft and see if it's there. One last step that I may have left out is when you select your "Hogcraft" pack from the selected list, you may need to add it to the list on the left, by clicking on the "add to active resource packs". (I don't remember exactly what it says)

Comment: Ben, great instructions! :)  It is in the appdata/roaming/.minecraft/resource packs folder.  I ran Minecraft and I see it is there but can not access it.  When I select "Hogcraft" (the zipped file) I do not see any option to "add to active resource packs".  I think this is the missing link for me in getting this to be successful.  Where is the option "add to active resource packs"?

Comment: It should be in the Minecraft window, when you choose your resource packs. Unfortunately I don't have access to Minecraft at the moment, so I'm running off memory at the moment. If you can hang on until I get home, and if nobody else gives the answer you're looking for, I'll give a proper answer when I get home. Sorry I haven't been of more help!

Comment: Ben, you have been a great help!  And I appreciate your persistence.  In my Minecraft window, when I click on Resource Packs, the only two options I see are at the bottom of the screen, "open resource pack folder" and "done."  I can't find an option to "add to active resource packs" in my resource pack folder or in Minecraft.  I understand you are not home and can offer more specific assistance at home.  No one else has yet been able to offer further assistance.  Today is my first time to use this site.  I have to log off now. I will check your instructions tomorrow.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful link for [installing your Resource Packs in Minecraft](http://www.minecrafttexturepacks.com/installing-texture-packs/)

To summarise:

1. Download your desired Minecraft Resource Pack from the web. **Do not unzip the downloaded folder**.
2. Open Minecraft
3. Go to "Options", then "Resource Packs"
4. Click on "Open Resource Pack Folder". If the window doesn't open, you'll have to find it manually through the Explorer/Finder.

   - For Windows: `%AppData%/.minecraft/resourcepacks`
   - For Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks`
   - For Linux: `~/.minecraft/resourcepacks`
5. Once here, drag and drop/copy and paste your **zipped** resource folder into this directory.
6. To be safe, restart Minecraft.
7. Go back into your Resource pack list in Minecraft. Here you should see your new Resource pack in the left-hand list. Click on it once.
8. An arrow (→) should appear. Click on it and it will be added to the "Selected Resource List". Double click on it again to activate it!

Answer (score 0):

I never, ever could drag and drop or copy and paste my resource packs when playing Minecraft.

What I did instead was when I either:

1. Clicked "open resource pack folder" and double clicked.
2. Manually inserted the resource pack inside the resource pack folder in `.minecraft`

Works like a charm.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding.  The Hogcraft folder is already inside the .minecraft/resource pack folder.  I just can't figure out how to access it when I am in the game.  When I am in the game, and click on Open Resource Pack Folder, I see it there but can not figure out how to access it.  Any further suggestions? :)

Comment: @MelissaAnn1970 I had this happen to me previously, and it was because I did it wrong. When you click in minecraft the resource packs there should be a icon with the resource pack and some short info, sorta like how minecraft server icons work in your multiplayer server tab. Try re-doing the process step by step.

Comment: Hi Chantola.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried to redo the process step by step, including redownloading the unzipped folder.  As an unzipped folder, I did not see any icon for available resource packs.  I see an icon on the Selected Resources Pack side (the default one).  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MelissaAnn1970 You should be seeing another resource pack under the default one which you can click. What steps are you going through?

Comment: Good question :)  My steps are: I downloaded the hogcraft version 2.3 from hogcraft.net.  Then I drag the hogcraft folder from the downloaded folder to my desktop.  Then I launched minecraft, went under options, then resource packs, then open resource packs folder and see the zipped hogcraft folder.  this is where I am stuck- I can't figure out how to access the hogcraft folder in the minecraft game.  It is already in my appdata-roaming-.minecraft-resourcepacks folder.